# Root URl of the servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to get the root url of my web application from one of the servlet.

If I deploy my application in "www.mydomain.com" I want to get the root url like "http://www.mydomain.com".

Same thing if I deploy it in local tomcat server with 8080 port it should give `http://localhost:8080/myapp`

Can anyone tell me how to get the root URL of my web application from servlet?

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String rootURL="";
        //Code to get the URL where this servlet is deployed

    }
}
```

Comment: String rootUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI(), "");

Comment: @Sllouyssgort doesn't work because `getRequestURI()` includes `myapp`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You do realize that the URL client sees (and/or types into his browser) and the URL served by the container your servlet is deployed on can be very different?

In order to get the latter, though, you have a few methods available on [HttpServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html):

- You can either call `getScheme()`, `getServerName()`, `getServerPort()` and `getContextPath()` and combine them using appropriate separators
- OR you can call `getRequestURL()` and remove `getServletPath()` and `getPathInfo()` from it.

Comment: I believe, `myapp` is a servlet name/path, in OP's example. What say you?

Answer (score 19):

This function helps you to get your base URL from a `HttpServletRequest`:

```
  public static String getBaseUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String scheme = request.getScheme() + "://";
    String serverName = request.getServerName();
    String serverPort = (request.getServerPort() == 80) ? "" : ":" + request.getServerPort();
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    return scheme + serverName + serverPort + contextPath;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you can't obtain the URL; but, there are workarounds for specific cases. See [Finding your application’s URL with only a ServletContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675730/finding-your-applications-url-with-only-a-servletcontext)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String getBaseUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String scheme = request.getScheme();
    String host = request.getServerName();
    int port = request.getServerPort();
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

    String baseUrl = scheme + "://" + host + ((("http".equals(scheme) && port == 80) || ("https".equals(scheme) && port == 443)) ? "" : ":" + port) + contextPath;
    return baseUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Write a scriptlet in the welcome file to capture the root path. I assume index.jsp is the default file. So put the following code in that

   `<%
   RootContextUtil rootCtx = RootContextUtil.getInstance();
   if( rootCtx.getRootURL()==null ){
   String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
   String uri = request.getRequestURI();
   String root = url.substring( 0, url.indexOf(uri) );
   rootCtx.setRootURL( root );
   }
   %>`
2. Use this variable wherever needed within the application directly by calling the value as

`String rootUrl = RootContextUtil.getInstance().getRootURL();`

NOTE: **No need to worry about protocols/ports/etc.. Hope this helps every one**