# How to get URL given path in Spring boot Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In thymeleaf we have:

```
<a th:href="@{/somepath}">Link</a>
```

It becomes:

```
<a href="http://hostname:port/somepath">Link</a>
```

I want to get the full URL given path like that in controller, like:

```
@GetMapping(path="/")
public String index(SomeInjectedClass cls) {
    String link = cls.someMethod('/somepath');
    // expected, link = http://hostname:port/somepath
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping(path="/home")
public String home(SomeInjectedClass cls) {
    String link = cls.someMethod('/somepath');
    // expected, link = http://hostname:port/somepath
    return "home";
}
```

**EDITED**
This question can be interpreted as this:

```
public static String APPLICATION_BASE_URL = "http://hostname:port";
function someMethod(String method){
    return APPLICATION_BASE_URL + method;
}
```

I think that `APPLICATION_BASE_URL` is ugly since i can deploy everywhere. I wonder there is a pretty function in spring boot or even java to get the base URL of my application.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629102/root-url-of-the-servlet/37908450#37908450) answers my question, although looks ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do it is using `HttpServletRequest`

```
@GetMapping(path="/")
public String index(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    String link = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL();
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: this will return my current url in these mapping. i want to get another path instead

Comment: what do u meant by another path?

Comment: edited my question, those links in both mapping will have same value

Comment: I upvoted this answer, because it answers the question as it is worded today (although the poster wanted in fact something else). *PS In fact it answers the posters question!* It helped me solve my issue. Thanks @pvpkiran

Answer (score 0):

Below one line code should work.

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/newPath").toUriString();
```

or

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().replacePath("/newPath").toUriString();
```

Comment: This will only append a path. I think the TO want a replacing procedure.

Comment: @Snickbrack, Please check the Edited section of the question and sample there. This solution gives same result which OP is asking

Comment: No, I have tested it and the `.path`-Method appends the `/newPath` instead of replacing it.

Comment: @Snickbrack, I'm getting the expected results when I tried from my side. You can try `.replacePath()` instead of `.path()`