# Url Problem while Developing on Localhost and deploy on Remote Virtual Server

Tags: java, tomcat, url, xhtml, remote-server

I have developed an WebApplication which runs on a Tomcat on my Notebook on Localhost. Now i have the task to deploy the Application to a remote Virtual Server. I coded all the redirects via JSF and a custom Servlet Class.For Example you press a Button and a Method gets called which redirects you to http://localhost:8080/myApp/some.xhtml. But when i Deploy the App to the remote Server i have to change all the redirects because it has now a different URL. Is there a way of mapping these URLS to their counterpart on the remote Server, so i don't have to change every single redirect in the xhtml Files and the Servlet? How is the way to go here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion 1.

Instead of redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/myApp/some.xhtml`, build the URL from a base URL (e.g. "http://localhost:8080/myApp/") and a path.  Then make the base URL a configuration parameter.

See also: [Root URl of the servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629102/root-url-of-the-servlet)

Suggestion 2.

Redirect to "/myApp/some.xhtml" and let the URI resolver deal with it.  Assuming that the URI is resolved in the context of the original URL, it should go to the correct place.