# specify variable context path in spring security (3.0.x)

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, contextpath

We are developing "box" web-product, so I cannot foreseen the environment where application is deployed. This application uses spring-security. But it is appeared that if Tomcat placed application not at the root then following configuration fails:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" >
    ....
    <sec:form-login login-page="/ui/Login" />
```

Following recommendation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6934712/149818 to use

`#{servletContext.contextPath}` doesn't work. User instead of http://foo/myApp/ui/Login is redirected to http://foo/ui/Login

So my question is

- either how to get #{servletContext.contextPath} alive
- or how to force spring-security recognize actual contextPath

Comment: I'm pretty sure that context path is appeded to `login-page` automatically. Which version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` class which handles the redirect will always include the context path as part of the URL (the sample apps have a context path, for example). Could you post the relevant section of the debug log where the redirect takes place? You should normally see a message from the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` as described in [the FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-anon-access-denied) and shortly after that "Redirecting to " followed by the URL.

Comment: @Luke Taylor - thanks a lot. Since I've started log everything became right - I've lost root '/' see my self answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great thanks to @Luke Taylor and @axtavt - my error is missing root '/' in the

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
     <sec:intercept-url pattern="/ui/Login" 
                        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
```

When '/' appears - #{servletContext.contextPath} starts work correctly.