# I need to create absolute URL's for my SPRING application using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SPRING application running (using spring boot) either directly on Java or on a Tomcat 7 server. I need to create absolute URL's for a couple of pages (mappings) so that these links can be sent via e-mail.

I thought this would be simple, but now it seems hard. I would prefer a solution that is 100% written in Thymeleaf, but if that is not possible, I can certainly provide Thymeleaf with some variables from my Java code.

Anyone solved this before in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should provide a server URL in a property file and than access it in Thymeleaf. You can do it by accessing Spring Bean in a view:

```
<div th:text="${@urlService.getApplicationUrl()}">...</div>
```

In the above example, the `urlService` is a Spring Bean.

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/675903/718515

You may be also interested in `#ctx` variable that gives you access to `servletContext`. See Thymeleaf docuementation: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#base-objects

I hope it helps!

Comment: The link to Thymeleaf documentation is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

I just did something similar where I was using Thymeleaf to generate an HTML email (and so of course links had to be made absolute). I used Thymeleaf's built-in `@{}` link syntax to create the appropriate URL relative to the server (since it calls the `HttpServletResponse.encodeURL()` which I needed to do as I had a custom implementation to do some additional URL munging), and then uses Spring's ServletUriComponentsBuilder to make the URL absolute using the HttpServletRequest server information.

```
<p th:with="
    relativeCustomerInfoPath=@{|/my/path/${customer.code}/info/|},
    customerInfoPath=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder).fromContextPath(#httpServletRequest).replacePath(relativeCouponPath).toUriString()}">
  Go see your info at 
  &lt;<a th:href="${customerInfoPath}" th:text="${customerInfoPath}">Link</a>&gt;.
</p>
```

There may be a better way, but this worked well for me and does the making of the URL absolute entirely within Thymeleaf (though using Spring's library).

Answer (score 0):

Today I made an integration that suggested using the full Url for compatibility.

> - The base should change according to enviroment (I just send it as attribute).
> - The last @{/js/i/dyn} is to get the contextPath.

```
<script th:src="${'https://' + base} + @{/js/i/dyn}"></script>
```

ref: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html