# How to get Server/Servlet Context without HttpServlet or HttpServletRequest?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications

**Suppose** I host a JavaEE WebApp on Payara/Glassfish (or any other WebContainer for that matter).
I would reach the Servlets under the address `https://a.b/appname/myservleturlpattern` or as `https://a.b/myservleturlpattern` if the VirtualServer-Config points to the app as default.

**Usually** I can get that address easily inside any HttpServlet (ServletContext).

**But now**, when I'm running a Background task (@Schedule) in a non-servlet class, how would I get that address?

**What I want**: get the app's base address `https://a.b/appname/` or as `https://a.b/` from any class, especially from non-Servlet classes. (Cant get  and don't need the `myservleturlpattern` because I'm not in a servlet.)

So far, my only **idea** is to listen to all my Servlets (extending the same custom HttpServlet anyway) and on the first call set a static variable, but thats really really unclean and hack-isch.

Any **better ideas**?

Comment: What do you want from the servlet context?

Comment: What I want: get the app's base address https://a.b/appname/ or as https://a.b/ from any class, especially from non-Servlet classes. (Cant get and don't need the myservleturlpattern because I'm not in a servlet.)

Comment: You can't get that information without a request. The container isn't aware of any of the routes a client may reach it, which is actually almost always numerous. It's available with a request because the client tells the container how it called the container. If you have to have this information I suggest you instead make an endpoint available and use a cron job to call it externally. Ideally your app should not depend on this, it makes deployments difficult. Your own solution doesn't work: what if no requests are made before the schedule?

Comment: Yeah, I know that my solution is not the best. Ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206594/how-to-get-server-servlet-context-without-httpservlet-or-httpservletrequest/53206997#53206997 has exactly the same problems as I do... Thought I can guarantee that I will not be behind load balancing or proxies.

Comment: Proper Linkt to other topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675730/finding-your-applications-url-with-only-a-servletcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) serves exactly this purpose but there may be better solutions depending on what you want to do with with it

Comment: Awesome! Thanx! Didnt think about the initializers...